# How do I solve "flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import filename"?

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple app.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return app.send_static_file('../../public/index.html')

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run it using `flask run` I get this error:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import app
```

My `FLASK_APP` is set to `{path-to-app}/app.py`, and I am running the command from the folder that the file is in.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score -1):

Your html file "index.html" needs to be in a folder called 'templates' which should be in the folder 'app.py' is also in.